# Duvida em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa noite e desculpe pelo titulo pouco objetivo mas me pareceu dificil titular essa questão mas vamos la!
Em um seletor de elementos exemplo `document.querySelector().anything` o atributo `anything` é aceito normalmente? eu posso digitar qualquer coisa no lugar, batata, lagosta e será aceito, caso eu faça `document.querySelector("#anyID").batata = "doce".` funciona normalmente. Me parece que a linguagem automaticamente cria o índice batata e atribui a string "doce" a ela... qual a utilidade disso em termos de programação?

Comment: Nenhuma. Isso será ignorado. O `JS` só utilizará o valor, se for um atributo válido.

Comment: não entendi o que quis dizer, como assim válido? pois esse atributo gerado "dinamicamente" aparenta ser válido kkk, tando que você pode invoca-lo após isso.

Comment: O que quer dizer com `anything`?

Comment: qualquer coisa, você pode digitar qualquer atributo para um elemento selecionado

Comment: @JefterRocha como disse o @MaííconFerreira, atributo e propriedade são diferentes. "o atributo anything é aceito normalmente?" não. O atributo será ignorado. É diferente de informar `title`, `style` etc que **SÃO** atributos válidos e que serão incorporados COMO ATRIBUTOS no HTML. E essa **propriedade** só será utilizada, só terá utilidade se você criar um código específico para utiliza-la, caso contrário será ignorada pelo `JS` pois (repito) são é um **atributo** válido.

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está meio torta mas acho que entendi, me corrija se estiver interpretado errado.

**Você está perguntando se, adicionar um atributo a um elemento usando DOM é comum(válido, aceito, normal, etc)?**

Bom, primeiro que você não está adicionando atributo, e sim propriedade ao objeto.

São coisas diferentes!

Adicionando propriedade ao objeto(não escreve no HTML):

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.data = "value";
console.log(input.data);
```

Adicionando atributo ao objeto(escreve no HTML e DOM):

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.setAttribute('data', 'value');
console.log(input.getAttribute("data"));
```